# Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

When I run my Rails app in WEBrick on Ubuntu, after upgrading to ruby-1.9.3-p327, I receive the following error:

> [rake --tasks] /home/dsilver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/em-dir-watcher-0.9.4/lib/em-dir-watcher.rb:7: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.

Any idea what's going on?

I've seen some posts connecting this to ImageMagick on Windows. I am on Ubuntu, but the app does use ImageMagick, and the ImageMagick functionality appears to have broken since the ruby upgrade from 1.9.2 to 1.9.3. I suspect a connection.

Thanks!

Comment: Still unsure what's going on, although I suspect it's a bug in the em-dir-watcher gem. That gem is a dependency of livereload, and the livereload gem appears to be deprecated in favor of guard-livereload. So I updated my Gemfile, which removed the em-dir-watcher gem, and the error vanished.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `Config` module has been renamed to `RbConfig`. It’s still possible to use the old name, for backwards compatibility, but Ruby [issues a warning](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_3_327/lib/rbconfig/obsolete.rb#L4) if you do.

The [`em-dir-watcher` gem uses the old name](https://github.com/mockko/em-dir-watcher/blob/v0.9.4/lib/em-dir-watcher.rb#L7), and so you see the warning when it’s loaded. Someone has already sent a [pull request](https://github.com/mockko/em-dir-watcher/pull/11) fixing this, however the last update to `em-dir-watcher` was over two years ago so it might not get merged.

This is a warning that is generated, not an error, so your code should actually still work okay. If you really want to get rid of the warning you could add something like this before you `require 'em-dir-watcher'`:

```
Object.send :remove_const, :Config
Config = RbConfig
```

This defines `Config` to be the same as `RbConfig`, which is what Ruby does anyway, but prevents the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can do (not recommended):

Go to the file **../lib/ruby/1.9/rbconfig/obsolete.rb**

Edit the file, the change is commenting the line **#warn ...**

With that change, eliminated the advice "warn"

Comment: If it's not recommended then why are you recommending it?  That's what an answer to a question is: a recommendation.

Comment: I feel that is a temporary solution instead of permanent and better solution, i don't know if the question (a guy that looking answer) need urgency for some fast solution